# Parallel fitting of single tf.keras.Model on single GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I'm trying to train a single model with a huge dataset on a single GPU. I don't mind setting smaller batch size, since I'll be running this for a while anyway, but what bothers me is that the GPU is utilized only by 25% when training the model. I have plenty of spare CPU and GPU capacity that could be used to fit the data faster. There seem to be a lot of computing capability lying on the table, and I could just traing 3-4 of these models in parallel. What I would like to do instead is to somehow run multiple copies of the same model.fit on a single gpu to consume the excess capacity and speed up training.

How do I do this?

Comment: That could be because of small batch size. Have you tried increasing it?

Comment: yes, I played with different batch sizes, and model training iterations actually take longer with huge batch sizes without increasing gpu utilization. Also, it's not because dataset takes long time to read. I keep it all in RAM

Comment: Batching is done on the CPU so once a batch is created it has to be transferred from the CPU->system meory-> CUDA device and when processing of the batch is complete the result is sent in the opposite direction. This transfer is slow and particularly with small batch sizes and simple networks, GPU spends a lot of time sitting idle. In many cases such nets are faster to train on the CPU.

Comment: Before doing all of this, find where is the bottleneck, you are wrongly assuming that more compute will lead to faster training time, this is only true if compute is the bottleneck.